# Error on Scope Variable While Using Tensorflow Hub

Tags: google-colaboratory, tensorflow-hub

I am using Colab to run a text analysis code. I am want to get [universal-sentence-encoder-large](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/3) from tensorflow_hub.
But anytime running the block containing the code below:

```
module = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/3")
```

I get this error:

```
    RuntimeError: variable_scope module_8/ was unused but the 
    corresponding name_scope was already taken.
```

I appreciate if you have any idea how this error can be fixed?

Comment: [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: have you found a solution for this problem? I'm getting similar error.

Comment: No, I ended up using Pytorch

Comment: The above problem arises when using TF 2.0 . Downgrading to 1.15.0 or lower will solve the problem.

Comment: I'm having same problem, any solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[TF Hub USE-3 Module](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/3) doesn't work with Tensorflow Version 2.0.

Hence, if you change the version from 2.0 to 1.15, it works without any error.

Please find the working code mentioned below:

```
!pip install tensorflow==1.15
!pip install "tensorflow_hub>=0.6.0"
!pip3 install tensorflow_text==1.15

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import numpy as np
import tensorflow_text

module = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/3")
```

Please find the [Github Gist](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/rmothukuru/dfcb943b81357557948c0256514ce769/hub_use_so_57742410.ipynb) of Google Colab as well.

Answer (score 5):

With tensorflow 2 in google colab you should use hub.load(url) instead of hub.Module(url)

Comment: This is not an answer. Please consider leaving a comment instead.

Comment: Thanks, I got the solution