# Elmo embeddings errors

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, embedding, elmo

i'm using ELMO to create embeddings for my dataset, i always get this error:

```
embed=elmo(data,signature="default",as_dict=True)["elmo"]
TypeError: 'AutoTrackable' object is not callable
```

my code is as simple as this:

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow as tf
elmo = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/3")
embeddings = elmo(
    ["the cat is on the mat", "dogs are in the fog"],
    signature="default",
    as_dict=True)["elmo"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the TensorFlow version. ELMo doesn't work with tensorflow 2, please refer TensorFlow Hub documentation to check the text embeddings supported in [version 1](https://tfhub.dev/s?module-type=text-embedding&tf-version=tf1) and [version 2](https://tfhub.dev/s?module-type=text-embedding&tf-version=tf2). Running the same code after changing the TensorFlow version to 1.15 will do the trick. You should also use hub.Module() with version 1(instead of hub.load). Please refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57742410/error-on-scope-variable-while-using-tensorflow-hub) to see how to change the version.